# ¿como plantear la siguiente sentencia en python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Tengo un algoritmo en el cual esta planteado tal cual y tengo que ejecutar ciertas ordenes en python como las plantea el algoritmo así que no puedo modificar, ¿Cómo puedo plantear la siguiente sentencia?

[image: An]

donde **An** es un angulo, y todo lo que esta con la raíz es una variable llamada distancia.

teóricamente se  que existe la función de python:

```
                   An=np.arctan2(y, x) * 180 / np.pi
```

pero el problema es que no poseo x,y y cuando intento hacer esto

```
              An=np.arctan2(distancia) * 180 / np.pi
```

me da error porque no es un formato admitido por python. gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2):

he encontrado la respuesta! An=np.arctan2(distancia) * 180 / np.pi 
esto es igual a escribir en python An=np.arctan2(y2-y1,x2-x1) * 180 / np.pi

Comment: Genial! yo iba a ponerte una solución en los comentarios, pero entonces no tenía suficiente reputación para ello :/

Comment: ok, y cual es tu solución? quizas el metodo que plantees tambien funciones

Comment: Era utilizando la librería math, pero no recuerdo bien, aun así lo hice con distancia y veo que lo has solucionado con y2-y1,x2-x1